# Diferença absurda no WHERE sem conversão BINARY

Tags: mysql

Eu implementei um INDEX na coluna "Nome", que é do tipo varchar binary (latin1_binary).

Esta query leva cerca de 1.5 segundos para executar:

```
SELECT Nome FROM contas WHERE IP='255.255.255.255' AND Nome != BINARY'uhdde23221' LIMIT 10;
```

Porém, esta leva 43 segundos:

```
SELECT Nome FROM contas WHERE IP='255.255.255.255' AND Nome != 'uhdde23221' LIMIT 10;
```

Esta, mesmo sem conversão binary, leva 0.001s:

```
SELECT * FROM contas WHERE Nome='uhdde23221';
```

Por que isso acontece? Sempre vou ter que usar "BINARY"?

Versão: 10.4.14-MariaDB

Comment: Acredito que exista uma diferença entre os dois, mas só testando, a diferença é que o `BINARY` diferencia maiúsculo e minúsculo (enquanto o sem, creio que não diferencie). Além disso, se esta é uma query frequente, experimente criar um index (IP, Nome), não sei se irá ajudar muito. Me parece que IP é mais importante que Nome, o nome só está no !=. E... se o `IP, Nome` forem únicos (não existem dados com mesmo IP e Nome), você pode simplesmente fazer `WHERE IP =` e então na sua aplicação ignora se o `Nome` for igual, as vezes é mais rápido que usar `IP =` junto com `Nome !=` para tirar 1 linha.

Comment: Na sua edição, como `Nome =`, você está usando o `=`, enquanto nas outros a igualdade é baseado na `IP =` (e o `Nome` está usando como  `Nome !=`).

Comment: Creio que a maneira certa de analisar seja utilizando o `explain` e `analyze` e vendo o plano de execução da query.

Comment: O tempo de 1.5s é normal visto que realmente não fiz um index em `IP`. O problema são os 43 segundos quando combino a coluna `Nome` com qualquer outra na cláusula `WHERE` sem converter a parte estática em `BINARY`. Isto não acontecia antes, somente depois que fiz um index em `Nome`. O que deveria acelerar a query acabou deixando ela absurdamente lenta por esse detalhe, e não sei o porquê.

OBS: A coluna `Nome` já é binária por padrão.